# preg_replace function for database and web security

Tags: php, mysql, forms, security, preg-replace

I was using a preg_replace function in a object oriented program to remove characters for security purposes. However the field will need to allow certain characters like @ or numbers etc. What can I place within a preg_replace function to secure my database but allow users to enter appropriate data. This data such as phone number, name, username, etc. The password is encrypted using MD5 Function.

I was told that using md5 and preg_replace were bad ideas. If so, what functions are available for me to use?

Comment: why exactly are you using preg_replace, and what characters are you removing? it sounds like you should not be using preg_replace at all. if you are trying to prevent sql injection, use mysql_real_escape_string(). on the other hand if you are simply trying to encrypt a password for storage in a database, you would hash it.

Answer (score 3):

To secure batabase use `mysql_real_escape_string`, `mysqli_real_escape_string`, PDO parameters binding depending on what you use. No need to replace anything with `preg_replace` before placing in database.

Comment: So to implement this I would do mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['example']) right? How secure is this compared to other algorithms such as SHA1

Comment: @KevinOluseunKarimu its not secure to store plain passwords escaped or not. You have to hash it.

Comment: Wow, wait. What are you talking about? Escaping data before saving in database and hashing with crypting algoritms are different (like soft and sweet). Escaping is used to prevent you database from SQL injections

Comment: I want to use the best security available for protecting submited data

Comment: @KevinOluseunKarimu You want to protect the submitted data from what?

Comment: I'm just talking about overall security. Using the best security possible.

Answer (score 1):

Relying solely on preg_replace for security isn't a good idea.  It can be useful for enforcing/standardizing things like phone number or date formats though.

Algorithms like MD5 and SHA1 are for hashing.  You can use it on any data, even dangerous untrusted input, and you'll always get a hexadecimal string.  However, because hashes are one-way, you cannot "decrypt" them back to the original input.

@dfsq is right - use those methods to securely save potentially dangerous input to your database.  The only case where you'd want to use a hash is for something like passwords, where nobody should ever be able to decrypt them.  (And if you do hash your passwords, make sure you salt them as well!)

Comment: A "salt" is a secret string you add to passwords before hashing them.  This makes it impractical to use a rainbow table attack to figure out your password. Rainbow tables are pre-generated lists of common passwords and their MD5 hash. A password of `password` would always hash to `5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`. But if you add the random string `OR8y9we8fw` to it `passwordOR8y9we8fw` hashes out to `4d2013d83c649a67b86079e00ab2c253` instead & wont appear in any hash table. The salt should be kept secret but even if the salt is stolen, it will still take a very long time to crack passwords.

Comment: Will you please explain that steps or algorithm to applying salt?

Comment: @KevinOluseunKarimu, take a look at this article: http://pbeblog.wordpress.com/2008/02/12/secure-hashes-in-php-using-salt/